# Benchmark workstation machine - tooling?

Tags: benchmarking, performance-testing

I've convinced my boss (for the second time actually - 2 different companies) to invest in new workstations with SSD's and I need to do a before and after benchmarking. I don't want to rely on timing VS2010 opening a solution, compile time etc. Does anyone know a good benchmarking tool for this purpose - not only disk IO, but also CPU etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many programms which let you do benchmarks on cpu,harddisk, gpu....
Maybe this website provides a solution for you :

- http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/5-free-benchmark-programs/

Comment: Excellent! I'll looks like SiSoft Sandra or Novabench might do the trick. Thanks.

Comment: Another random blog post with links to some benchmark tools: https://blogs.innovanathinklabs.com/best-cpu-benchmark-software-windows/  (originally posted as a somewhat spammy answer, but the recommendations are actually real benchmarks that AFAIK aren't spyware or otherwise nasty to install.)